# ZSH Listen to Command Not Found

Tags: shell, zsh

For those who may not know what  [nvbn/thefuck](https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck)
app is, it corrects errors in previous console commands. What I wish to do is, run `fuck` command automatically if zsh throws a command not found error. There wasn't such information on its documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out experimental mode in [nvbn/thefuck](https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck). Quoting:

```
The default behavior of The Fuck requires time to re-run previous commands. When in instant mode, The Fuck saves time by logging output with script, then reading the log.
```